# Setstate not updating in CustomInput type='checkbox' handler

Tags: reactjs, setstate, reactstrap

This is the render method, how i am calling the handler and setting the reactstrap checkbox.

```
    this.state.dishes.map(
                    (dish, i) => (
                      <div key={i}>
                          <CustomInput
                            type="checkbox"
                            id={i}
                            label={<strong>Dish Ready</strong>}
                            value={dish.ready}
                            checked={dish.ready}
                            onClick={e => this.onDishReady(i, e)}
                          />

                        </div>))
```

The handler for the onClick listener, I've tried with onchange as well but it apears that onchange doesnt do anything, idk why?

```
  onDishReady = (id, e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    var tempArray = this.state.dishes.map((dish, i) => {
      if (i === id) {


        var temp = dish;
        temp.ready = !e.target.value
        return temp
      }
      else {
        return dish
      }
    })
    console.log(tempArray)
    this.setState({
      dishes: tempArray

    });

  }
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error? Please provide more context, like the code for `CustomInput`. I think you may need to access `e.target.checked` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event.target.value` isn't the "toggled" value of an input checkbox, but rather `event.target.checked` is.

```
onDishReady = index => e => {
  const { checked } = e.target;
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const newDishes = [...prevState.dishes]; // spread in previous state
    newDishes[index].ready = checked; // update index
    return { dishes: newDishes };
  });
};
```

The rendered `CustomInput` reduces to

```
<CustomInput
  checked={dish.ready}
  id={i}
  label={<strong>DishReady</strong>}
  onChange={this.onDishReady(i)}
  type="checkbox"
/>
```

No need to pass in a `value` prop since it never changes.

*Note:* Although an `onClick` handler does appear to work, semantically it isn't quite the correct event, you want the logic to respond to the checked value of the checkbox changing versus a user clicking on its element.

[image: Edit checkbox array toggle demo]

Comment: Thanks alot @drew for your help but i don't know why but onChange is still not working in my code(maybe its because of reactstrap custominput). By using onClick, its going into the handler but still not updating the dishes array.

Comment: Got it, there seems to be some issue with the data that i am getting from the backend Api, it is setting the dishes array on componentWillMount.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    this.setState(function (state) {
        const dishes = [...state.dishes];
        dishes[id].ready = !e.target.value;
        return dishes;
    });
```

Comment: FYI this method mutates the current state object.